# Manually Adding Preconnect tag after the <head> in Genesis Theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, genesis

I want to manually add the preconnect tag after the **< head >TAG** of genesis child theme.

For Example I want this code just after the **< head >TAG** of genesis child theme WordPress:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="//fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link rel="preconnect" href="//fonts.googleapis.com" crossorigin>
<link rel="preconnect" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com" crossorigin>
```

Got something relevant but its for prefetch and didn't worked for me.

```
<?php
function mk_dns_prefetch() {
  echo '<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//secure.gravatar.com" />
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//apis.google.com" />
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com" />
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mk_dns_prefetch', 0 );
```

Comment: "Didn't work for me" is pretty vague. Also, that second code is missing `';` to end the echo statement. Did you edit it in the editor, or did you try to run it like this?

Comment: I tried to put it in the function file of the Genesis child theme but it was showing some sort of errors.@janh